# Return raw probabilities of sklearn's Gaussian Naive Bayes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, outliers

I am using GaussianNB of Scikit-Learn to make supervised classification. When using the method "predict_proba", the sum of probalities is always equal to 1.

What I would like to return is the real value of the fitted gaussian distribution because my dataset contains many outliers. If I had 3 identified categories, I would like the model to tell me : "There is 10% of being category A, 0.5% of being category B and 4% of being category C". In other words, it is more likely to be an outlier.

Does sklearn return this result aswell ? Should I make the math based on mean and standard deviation ?

Comment: You could just classify with a 4th category, with the 4th representing outliers that don't fit your 3 defined categories.

Comment: Inside `predict_proba()`, GaussianNB first calculates the joint log likelihood and then normalizes that to give probabilities (that sum upto 1). So you may use `_joint_log_likelihood()`  method to get the unscaled values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've finally used is the following :

```
gaussian_model = naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
jll = gaussian_model._joint_log_likelihood(X) 
raw_proba = np.exp(jll)
```

`raw_proba` is not between 0 and 1 but as I only want to rank results I don't really care about the figure itself.

Comment: If you don't care about the figures and just need to rank, what difference does it make to obtain the `_joint_log_likelihood` like you do or normalise them from `0` to `1` to get their probabilities as in `predict_proba()`?